# Where is the right place to put Thread in C# test automation

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I have used the Thread in the middle of the two coding lines. Is it the correct place to keep

```
var branch = new SelectElement(webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("CompanyBranchId")));
        Thread.Sleep(4000);
        branch.SelectByText("Globex Branch Two");
```

Comment: You should not need any `Thread.Sleep` in well designed tests. So the most correct answer would be *nowhere*.

Comment: A better option than `Thread.Sleep()` is to have your code wait until it finds the element it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Thread.Sleep()` is the last thing you should do when designing selenium tests. It unreliable/inefficient. Make an instance of WebDriverWait (if you don't already have one) and use it's `Until()` function. Example for what you're trying to do:

```
        IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

        var branch = new SelectElement(webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("CompanyBranchId")));
        wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Globex Branch Two')]")).Displayed);
        branch.SelectByText("Globex Branch Two");
```